# Where the data will be stored when using Sharedpreferences

Tags: android

Hi please tell me whats wrong in the code I am learning shared preferences and after using them my app is not running it's stopped by displaying unfortunately example stopped.where will be the data stored i am not finding any file related to preferences in DDMS.`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences(MY_FILE,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor e=sp.edit();
    e.putString("name", textview1.getText().toString());
    e.commit();
    String name=sp.getString("name","");
    Log.i("NAme","name entered:"+ name);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MenuScreen.class);
                 startActivity(i);
                }

        });         
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized `textview1`. Add something like

```
textview1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id);
```

after `setContentView()`.

No preferences are saved as the program terminates before the sharedpreferences edit is committed.

To answer the question in the title, the shared preferences are stored under your app package's data directory.

For app crashes, always first have a look at the exception stacktrace in logcat. Include it in the questions you post, too.

Comment: Thank u lot. But i am not able to find the file name i specified in the data directory.should i do any settings to view that file